# Generic Method in Non-Generic Class

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to use a generic method so I don't have to repeat code. I have tried:

```
private Listener createListenerAdapter(Class<T> clazz)
{ 
   // do something
}
```

(`clazz` being important because `class` is reserved).

But Netbeans complains that : "Cannot find symbol class T".

I am going to be passing in a few different classes that have the same methods on them. Where am I supposed to define T?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Declare the method as:

```
private <T> Listener createListenerAdapter(Class<T> clazz)
```

See the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) for more information.

**Edit:** If `T` isn't related to the return type you could also just use a wildcard:

```
private Listener createListenerAdapter(Class<?> clazz)
```

**Edit 1:** If `clazz` is meant to represent a type of `Listener`, you could define bounds to restrict the caller (to avoid casts and potential runtime exceptions):

```
private <L extends Listener> L createListenerAdapter(Class<L> clazz)
```

Or with the wildcard:

```
private Listener createListenerAdapter(Class<? extends Listener> clazz)
```

But that depends on how `clazz` is used in the body.

Comment: `clazz` is a GUI widget in GWT.

Comment: Okay, so probably `Class<? extends Widget>` is the best fit.

Comment: Is there a way to call a method on `clazz` inside createListenerAdapter() that corresponds to a method inside the class? So if I pass in `ButtonWidget` I want to be able to call `clazz.setEnable(true)`. All widgets have the same method call. I am passing in `ButtonWidget` as `createListenerAdapter(myWidget.getClass());` `clazz.setEnable(true)` does not work because it thinks I am asking for a method on `Class<?>`

Comment: `setEnable` is an instance method right? You would need to use `clazz` to instantiate a new `Widget` and then call the method on it.

Comment: Yes, it is an instance method. I have several classes that derive from the same superclass, but is there a way to tell which subclass was passed in? I tried `Class<? extends MySuperClass>` but that doesn't give me the subclass. There are several different subclasses.

Comment: Well the idea behind polymorphism is that you shouldn't have to know. If they share a common interface/superclass you can just treat them all like that and not worry about their implementation details.

Comment: Understood. I guess I am just wondering why if in the parameter I put `Class<? extends MySuperWidget> clazz` that Netbeans complains that it cannot find the symbol .setEnable when it exists in the superclass `MySuperWidget`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21540/discussion-between-paul-bellora-and-0a0d)

Answer (score 4):

Generic declarations can also be made at method-level by parametrizing them like this:

```
private <T> Listener createListenerAdapter(Class<T> clazz)
{ 
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the type (unlikely, but you may be trying to avoid a raw type warning):

```
private Listener createListenerAdapter(Class<?> clazz)
{ 
   // do something, without knowing the T of the clazz
}
```